# Can I prosecute newspaper for photographing me without my consent?

Tags: legal, privacy

I accompanied someone to court who was charged and we were snapped by a journalist upon leaving. The photo is obvious to any who know of me locally even though my face was obscured! Neighbours recognised me and are asking questions I should not have to face. I feel my privacy has been invaded. What rights do I have? I requested it be deleted but they cropped me off 1 pic instead. I am still visible in another that is still being published online!
Do I have a case?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is requesting a legal opinion, for which https://law.stackexchange.com/ may be more appropriate.

Comment: (in the UK) There is no legal right to privacy in public places.

Comment: Why do you think anyone needs your consent to photograph you? Also, laws are different in different jurisdictions. Where are you?

Answer (score 2):

You have no case... if you didn't want to be associated with said individual/situation, then you should not have associated yourself with it.

Even [countries which require permission](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Country_specific_consent_requirements) to take/publish pictures of individuals taken in public (e.g. Brazil, Spain, Switzerland) have exclusions allowing journalistic use of such images w/o consent. The only case you might have is if the information being put out in association with the image is factually false.